# Online/non batch mode learning + semi-supervised learning

Tags: machine-learning

I got a set of data in a form(around 5000 points) :

```
var1 var2 var3 var4 
 0.1  0.2  0.4  0.5
 0.1  0.2  0.2  0.5
 0.1  0.9  0.4  0.6
 0.9  0.9  0.8  0.9
 0.1  0.1  0.4  0.8
         .
         . 
         .
```

The values have range from zero to one. The higher the value the higher the chances to get classified as 1. However, the data is unlabeled and I do not know which `var` has higher weight.

Originally I am weighting equally all the variables with `1/4` (1/number_of_variables) and get the median value of the results, classify the values up to median with 1 and down of median to 0:

```
var1 var2 var3 var4 score output
 0.1  0.2  0.4  0.5   0.3    0
 0.1  0.2  0.2  0.5   0.25   0
 0.1  0.9  0.4  0.6   0.5    1
 0.9  0.9  0.8  0.9   0.875  1
 0.1  0.1  0.4  0.8   0.35   0
         .
         . 
         .
```

Later, a user can re-label 10 to 20 points out of the 5000 points.(the user-defined labels are considered the true one).

How can I update the model in order to take into account the labels of the user? As a user can label in different times I was thinking of a compination of online learning and a semi-supervised approach. How would you approach the whole task?

**Edit**:
A main idea that I had is the following:

1. Consider each `var` individually and classify each point with `1` if the value is higher than the mean value of the `var` column and `0` if it is less.
2. Train the above results individually with logistic regression.(Each `var` is trained to a different model.
3. Give an initial weight to each model(for example the value of 1)
4. When a user classify some examples the models are evaluated throught a simple adaboost algorithm and the weights are updated.

Do you think it could be a way of doing?

Comment: Your initial *model* doesn't seem very robust (unless you have *very* good data). Can't you get the *user labels* from the beginning and train from there? Unless you do some kind of density based clustering/classification, I don't know if it is worth *training a model* before the *user labels* (true annotations) arrive.

Comment: I think a better starting point would be related to a naive Bayes classifier.  It then sounds like you might want a weighted version, that adjusts weights based on the user input.  Alternatively, a simple logistic regression might suffice.

Comment: @imaluengo I agree that  it doesnt seem robust. On the other hand it is known that 'the higher the values the higher the chances to get classified as 1'. So It could be an initial way of 'labeling' until I have true labeled data from users.